# How to select a master processor randomly in MPI programming?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, message-passing

I need to select one processor from my Comm to do some works ( I don`t want other processors do the work ). 
Since I split my Comm to the groups, I cannot always pick one specific rank ( for example 0) as my master. I need to choose it from my current comm. Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of a process is always relative to a communicator. After you split your processes, you can just take process 0 in the new communicator to perform the work you want.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by suszterpatt is correct and this is what you should normally do. Nevertheless, I'd like to address the title of the question of **randomly** selecting a master process. To do that

1. Every rank in the communicator generates a random number
2. Distribute the random number and the rank number using `MPI_Allreduce` with [`MPI_MAXLOC`](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node79.html).
3. Now every rank in the communicator can use the rank as a master.